# Знак препинания в сложносочинённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, ссп, сложное-предложение

**Подружись с тайм-менеджментом (запятая, тире, отсутствие знака) и ты сможешь даже выгадывать себе время для безделья.**

Требуется ли здесь знак препинания? Если да, то какой?
Я бы, если честно, здесь не ставил вообще никакого знака. Уж очень предложения связаны интонацией. С другой стороны, предложение не подпадает ни под один из случаев, когда запятую можно не ставить (предложения не оба побудительные, нет формально одинаковой объединяющей интонации; предложения не безличные и не неопределенно-личные с одинаковой формой сказуемого). Можно поставить тире, как обозначение следствия или неожиданного присоединения, однако я, как автор, не предполагаю паузу между предложениями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подружись с тайм-менеджментом,  и ты сможешь даже выгадывать себе время для безделья.

Подружись с тайм-менеджментом —  и ты сможешь даже выгадывать себе время для безделья.

1) **Нет никаких оснований** не ставить в этом предложении  запятую или другой знак.

2) **Пауза здесь в любом случае будет присутствовать**, только длительность ее при постановке запятой будет меньше, чем при постановке тире.

3) В предложениях такого содержания и структуры **чаще ставится тире,** подчеркивающее взаимообусловленность действий. А если вы себе такой задачи не ставите, то выбирайте запятую, третьего не дано.